# Angular project refresh result 404 page on the site

Tags: angular, deployment, angular-ui-router

On my local computer, the angular project works well.

So I deployed it to the server via FTP.

```
ng build
```

And I uploaded dist file to server.
Then, the url works.

```
www.miexchange.tech
```

And if I click any button to go other page, it works well.

But if I click refresh button or `F5` then I can't get current page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgdoO.png)

Please look at the image, now it works well.
But if I click refresh button, then this page is displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUO2O.png)

Please let me know the reason.

Comment: https://www.code-sample.com/2018/05/angular-5-6-7-hashlocationstrategy.html read the tutorial HashLocationStrategy issues. `useHash:true`

Answer (score 0):

What ist the base href in your `dist/index.html`?
Try changing it to

```
  <base href="/your/deployment/directory/on/the/server">
```

For more information, you can read https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Bansi29, you are right

This problem is due to hash.

There are 2 methods.

1) Insert `{useHash: true}` to app-routing.module.ts

```
app-routing.module.ts
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), { useHash: true }],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [
        TableDataService,
        RegularTablesResolver,
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ModalComponent,
    ]
})
```

2) Sometimes useHash true occurs error like this

```
TS2322: Type '{ useHash: boolean; }' is not assignable
```

On this case, you can follow these step.

```
app.module.ts
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

After that, please insert `{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}` to `@NgModule providers`.

ex.

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: great. To enable HashLocationStrategy in an Angular application we pass {useHash: true} when we are providing our routes with RouterModule